# Matrix second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have a system of 2 coupled second order linear ordinary differential equations.
Suppose we have $A(t) X'' + B(t) X' + C(t) X = 0$ with $A,B,C$ are $2 \times 2$ time dependent matrices.

I need to know, under fairly general conditions, when it is possible to diagonalize the system to uncouple the two degrees of freedom.

Any resources will be appreciated.

Comment: If you take out the matrices,... A,B, and C then try to solve for X'' + X' + X = 0 you get the oscillatory equations r^2 + r + c = 0 which has one general solution. Given that information, you know that A, B and C must have a form that satisfies those equations. A could equal [r^2, 0, 0, 0], B could equal [r, 0, 0, 0]... etc. I'm not 100% certain what you mean by decouple the equations which is why this is only a comment. Do you want Acceleration to be independent of Velocity or something like that? What prevents you from diagonalizing the Matrix equations?

Comment: Set $X_1 := X$, $X_2 := X'$, $\Bbb X := (X_1,X_2)^T$, $\Bbb A := diag(I,A)$, and $\Bbb B := \begin{pmatrix}0 & I\\-C & -B\end{pmatrix}$. Then the ODE is equivalent to $\Bbb A\Bbb X' = \Bbb B\Bbb X$. Hence, if $A(t)$ is invertible for each $t$, then $\Bbb X' = \Bbb A^{-1}\Bbb B\Bbb X$. Don't know if this helps.